# How to find a total average student mark in Python

Tags: python

I can't find total average mark of all students from the list.

Here is my solution, but it gives me a wrong answer:

```
fname=input('Enter the file name: ')
print()

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    print("Student Marks")
    count = 0
    total = 0

    for line in f:
        

        words = line.split()
        names = []
        marks = []
        
        for word in words:
            try:
                value = float(word)
            except ValueError:
                names.append(word)
            else:
                marks.append(value)
                        
        name = ' '.join(names)
                
        if not marks:
            pass
        else:
            print(name,' ', marks)
            
            count1 = 0
            total1 = 0
            i = 0

            while i < len(marks):
                #print(fname[i], ":", fname [i+1])
                count1 = count1 +1
                total1 = total1 + float (marks [i])
                i=i+1
                t = total1/count1

                
            print("avarage:", t, '\n')
            count = count+1

            tm = (total+t)/count
            print (tm)
```

Here is what I get when I run the code:

```
Enter the file name: sm.txt

Student Marks
Jean Paul Alarie   [56.0]
avarage: 56.0 

56.0
Juan Manuel Bienvenida   [72.6, 12.0]
avarage: 42.3 

21.15
Janet Brimfield   [66.3, 71.0]
avarage: 68.65 

22.883333333333336
Helen Jane Burnett   [54.0]
avarage: 54.0 

13.5
Bernard Galpin   [45.0, 66.2, 32.0]
avarage: 47.73333333333333 

9.546666666666665
Alexander Adam Janssen   [41.0, 21.0]
avarage: 31.0 

5.166666666666667
Struan Kilgour   [79.0, 82.5, 45.5]
avarage: 69.0 

9.857142857142858
Pierre Antoine Lajoie   [56.2, 45.5]
avarage: 50.85 

6.35625
Hamish McDonald   [66.5, 91.0]
avarage: 78.75 

8.75
Shakeel Mirza   [12.0]
avarage: 12.0 

1.2
Sidney Rickard   [88.0, 78.0, 84.4]
avarage: 83.46666666666667 

7.587878787878788
Sharlene Urry   [54.5]
avarage: 54.5 

4.541666666666667
Karl James Richard White   [62.0, 59.5, 41.2, 66.0]
avarage: 57.175 

4.398076923076923
>>>
```

Here is the expected answer:

```
>>>
Enter a filename: Student Marks.txt
Student Marks
Jean Paul Alarie:
Marks: 56.0, Average: 56.0
Juan Manuel Bienvenida:
Marks: 72.6, 12.0, Average: 42.3
Janet Brimfield:
Marks: 66.3, 71.0, Average: 68.65
Helen Jane Burnett:
Marks: 54.0, Average: 54.0
Bernard Galpin:
Marks: 45.0, 66.2, 32.0, Average: 47.73
…
Average: 54.26
>>>
```

Comment: You reset `marks` for each line of the file. You could add another list e.g. `all_marks` which you initialize with `[]` before the for-loop. Then append each mark to `all_marks`, too, and use it for calculation of the total average.

Comment: In the loop you need `total += total1` then outside the loop `tm=total/count`

Comment: Can we also see the file you are opening?

Comment: By "total average", did you mean "overall average"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all of us, it appears you need to get accommodated to the nuances of when and where to have the correct indentation for printing, totaling, averaging, and print formatting.  After building a copy of the grade/marks file and running the program, following is a refactored version of your program to provide the data and report format you appear to want.

```
fname=input('Enter the file name: ')
print()

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    print("Student Marks")
    count = 0
    total = 0

    for line in f:
        
        words = line.split()
        names = []
        marks = []
        
        for word in words:
            try:
                value = float(word)
            except ValueError:
                names.append(word)
            else:
                marks.append(value)
                        
        name = ' '.join(names)
                
        if not marks:
            pass
        else:
            print(name,  end="")
            for item in marks:
                print(" ", item,  end="")
            
            count1 = 0
            total1 = 0
            i = 0

            while i < len(marks):
                #print(fname[i], ":", fname [i+1])
                count1 = count1 +1
                total1 = total1 + float (marks [i])
                i=i+1
                t = total1/count1
                
            print(" Average:", "%.2f" % t)
            total = total + t
            count = count + 1

    tm = (total)/count
    print ()
    print ("Total Average: ", "%.2f" % tm)
```

Following are some key items to note:

- In the "else:" section where the name and marks are being printed, the name is printed and then a specialized "for" loop structured for reading lists is used to split out and list any and all marks for a student.
- The subsequent "while" loop is set to the same level as the name printing to total up the marks and derive an average for the student.
- Once the average for the student has been calculated and printed, that average is added to the total average value for subsequent report averaging after all of the students have been processed.
- Use of the end="" formatting in the print statement is used for aesthetic purposes to not send a newline character to the output and produce the desired type of report noted in your original narrative.
- And, floating point formatting is used for printing the final average value.

With those tweaks to the refactored code, following is the sample output utilizing the student mark data.

```
@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Students$ python3 Students.py 
Enter the file name: Marks.txt

Student Marks
Jean Paul Alarie  56.0 Average: 56.00
Juan Manuel Bienvenida  72.6  12.0 Average: 42.30
Janet Brimfield  66.3  71.0 Average: 68.65
Helen Jane Burnett  54.0 Average: 54.00
Bernard Galpin  45.0  66.2  32.0 Average: 47.73
Alexander Adam Janssen  41.0  21.0 Average: 31.00
Struan Kilgour  79.0  82.5  45.5 Average: 69.00
Pierre Antoine Lajoie  56.2  45.5 Average: 50.85
Hamish McDonald  66.5  91.0 Average: 78.75
Shakeel Mirza  12.0 Average: 12.00
Sidney Rickard  88.0  78.0  84.4 Average: 83.47
Sharlene Urry  54.5 Average: 54.50
Karl James Richard White  62.0  59.5  41.2  66.0 Average: 57.17

Total Average:  54.26
```

You might want to consult some Python tutorial manuals and/or online tutorials for further information to what was done to the refactored code, but go ahead and try out these suggestions and see if it meets the spirit of your project.